# locate the numeric position of a non numeric index value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Consider the series `s` below:

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(18, 0, -3), list('ABCDEF'))
s

A    18
B    15
C    12
D     9
E     6
F     3
dtype: int32
```

I want to get the numeric position of `'D'`

This will do it, but I think we can all agree this is gross:

```
s.reset_index().index.to_series()[s.reset_index().iloc[:, 0] == 'D'].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
print(s.index.get_loc('D'))
3
```

Comment: Looks like the built-in for such a task, lovely!

Comment: Note: this returns an array if there is more than one 'D' in the index!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.searchsorted(s.index.values,'D')
```

Or use the method, like so -

```
s.index.searchsorted('D')
```

Comment: I love that you provided the numpy solution then found the pandas solution afterwards ;-).  You should add the numpy tag to my post.

Comment: @piRSquared That's the beauty of answering questions, specially with tags that I am really not familiar with! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
m = s.index == 'D'
idx = m.argmax() if m.any() else None
```