# Function that depends on the row number

Tags: python, pandas, numbers, row

In pandas, is it possible to reference the row number for a function.  I am not talking about .iloc.

iloc takes a location i.e. a row number and returns a dataframe value.

I want to access the location number in the dataframe.

For instance, if the function is in the cell that is 3 rows down and 2 columns across, I want a way to return the integer 3.  Not the entry that is in that location.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example with an actual DataFrame?

Comment: Could this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199288/getting-the-integer-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe-row-fulfilling-a-condition

Comment: I think yuo need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

Comment: There is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38441888/2901002) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])

df
```

[image]

And the row `row`

```
row = df.ix['a']

row

c    1
d    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

There is nothing about this row that indicates that it was the first row of `df`.  That information is essentially lost... sort of.

You can take @jezrael's advice and use `get_loc`

```
df.index.get_loc(row.name)

0
```

But this only works if your index is unique.

Your only other option is to track its position when you get it.  The best way to do that is:

Use `enumerate` on `df.iterrows()`

```
for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    print "row position: {:>3d}\nindex value: {:>4s}".format(i, idx)
    print row, '\n'

row position:   0
index value:    a
c    1
d    2
Name: a, dtype: int64 

row position:   1
index value:    b
c    3
d    4
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldnt add a code sample but Im on my phone.  piRSquared confirmed my fears when he said the info is lost.  I guess ill have to do a loop everytime or add a column with numbers ( that will get scrambled if i sort them : / ).

Thanks everyone.